# how to delete an item by uid dgraph

Tags: node.js, graph

I am using cloud stub and the npm package `dgraph-js` I am trying to delete a item but it is not working

I have tried two different ways and none of them are working. I just want to delete the node and all of its pointers. How can I do this in DQL by dgraph-js

```
async function DeletePostD(username: string, postId: string): Promise<boolean> {
    const txn = dgraphClient.newTxn();

    try {
        console.log("deleting post", postId);
        const postUid = await GetPostUid(postId);
        if (!postUid) return false;
        const mutation = new dgraph.Mutation();
        const p = {
            uid: postUid,
        };
        mutation.setDeleteJson(p);
        const didDel = await txn.mutate(mutation);
        console.log(didDel.getUidsMap());
        if (didDel.getUidsMap().arr_.length <= 0) return false;
        await txn.commit();
        return true;
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return false;
    } finally {
        await txn.discard();
    }
}
```

The second function uses the nquads

```
async function DeletePostD(username: string, postId: string): Promise<boolean> {
    const txn = dgraphClient.newTxn();

    try {
        console.log("deleting post", postId);
        const postUid = await GetPostUid(postId);
        if (!postUid) return false;
        const mutation = new dgraph.Mutation();
        const p = {
            uid: postUid,
            
        }
        mutation.setDelNquads(`<${postUid}> * * .`);
        const didDel = await txn.mutate(mutation);
        console.log(didDel.getUidsMap());
        if (didDel.getUidsMap().arr_.length <= 0) return false;
        await txn.commit();
        return true;
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return false;
    } finally {
        await txn.discard();
    }
}
```

these both do not work with no error code. The item exists in the `Post` type and definently can be seen through a regular query